# Ubuntu 22.04.2 | Random Freeze Problem

Tags: 22.04, 64-bit, freeze, amd-graphics, amdgpu

Can't fix this problem for a month.

Randomly I do something, change tab or do simple tasks my screen crashes, can't move cursor, then monitor off (become black for 2 seconds), then back to normal but frozen and I must restart my laptop.

Log:

```
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 61710 Comm: kworker/u32:1 Not tainted 5.19.0-32-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 20QJS0GG00/20QJS0GG00, BIOS R13ET53W(1.27 ) 07/28/2022
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: Workqueue: amdgpu-reset-dev drm_sched_job_timedout [gpu_sched]
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: Call Trace:
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  <TASK>
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  show_stack+0x52/0x69
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x49/0x6d
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  dump_stack+0x10/0x18
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  amdgpu_do_asic_reset+0x2b/0x441 [amdgpu]
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  amdgpu_device_gpu_recover_imp.cold+0x4e4/0x7e1 [amdgpu]
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  amdgpu_job_timedout+0x15e/0x190 [amdgpu]
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x84/0x290
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  drm_sched_job_timedout+0x6d/0x120 [gpu_sched]
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  process_one_work+0x21f/0x400
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x3a0/0x3a0
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  kthread+0xee/0x120
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel:  </TASK>
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: MODE2 reset
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled.
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F400900000
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: [drm] PSP is resuming...
Feb 27 11:16:50 fichony kernel: [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf47fc00000 for PSP TMR
Feb 27 11:16:51 fichony kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
Feb 27 11:16:51 fichony kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
Feb 27 11:16:51 fichony kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Feb 27 11:16:52 fichony kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_2.1.0 test failed (-110)
Feb 27 11:16:52 fichony kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq.cold [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable failed
Feb 27 11:16:52 fichony kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <gfx_v9_0> failed -110
Feb 27 11:16:52 fichony kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(12) failed
Feb 27 11:16:52 fichony kernel: amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Feb 27 11:16:52 fichony kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Failed: -110
Feb 27 11:17:01 fichony CRON[67852]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 27 11:17:01 fichony CRON[67853]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 27 11:17:01 fichony CRON[67852]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 27 11:17:02 fichony kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma0 timeout, signaled seq=312097, emitted seq=312097
Feb 27 11:17:02 fichony kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process opera pid 50728 thread opera:cs0 pid 50732
```

System information:

[image: My System Info Screenshot]

Tried reinstalling Ubuntu, tried "WaylandEnable", installing custom drivers for GPU, but nothing worked.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this problem too recently when my kernel went from 5.15.0-60-generic to 5.19.0-32 generic.  Downgrading back to the 5.15 line fixed the exact same freezes you are hitting.  I believe if you look at your syslog you'll see VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS just as your system freezes.  Looking around I saw some posts saying the 5.19.19 (believe that was the version) was suppose to have the gpu fix in it, but the 32 version I had still hit it.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's been 2 days already and I have no problem with crashes. :)

Comment: FYI the 6.0 kernel appears to no longer have this issue.